# Where can one find the Sava and Yanuka in the Zohar?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, zohar

I've heard of a section of Zohar that deals with a wunderkind who enlightened educated rabbis, and a section that deals with a wise old man. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yanuka: Zohar Devarim, Balak (3:186a–192a)

Saba DeMishaptim: Zohar Shemot, Mishpatim (2:94b-95)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!